# How to control what buffer netty uses for read?

Tags: netty

I want to have very specific control of what buffer Netty uses when it calls read(). How do I manage this?

Also: It would be convenient for me to de-couple a read event from the actual reading. But I can get around that (mostly) by removing interest in OP_READ. But it'd be better for me if I had a read_ready() event and could call (or not call) the actual read w/ a ByteBuf at a time of my own choosing.

I tried looking into the NioSocketChanel implementation but I got lost very quickly. It looks like it allocated a new buffer for every read? (I assume the allocater impl just hands back a cached one).

How do I ensure the OS call to read copies the bytes to a specific place in memory?

Or has this feature been paved over for the convenience of the 95% use cases that don't need or care about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, it's been a while. I think the answer is "Can't be done".
I'll delete this comment and update this question if it turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came back to this again after a while.

You can write you own ByteBufAllocator and pass it to the channel config to control where read gets it's buffer from.

However, you're really fighting the framework. I decided to use something else.

Comment: Good decision. I took a good look at Netty when it first appeared, and it seemed to me to be at right-angles to NIO, rather than being built on top of it, what with having its own buffers, threads, etc. NIO is already a framework, and it sounds like that's the level you should be operating at.